# UITextView.highlight automatically scrolls to bottom of document

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I use a UITextView to display documents.   Within the document, the user can tap on a word, and it will be highlighted in red.

This works fine, except when the document is bigger than the size of the UITextView.   When I call this code:

```
myTextView.highlight(charPos: wordIndexInDocument, length: wordLength)
```

the word is correctly highlighted, but the document scrolls to the bottom.

I have tried the following, which was recommended elsewhere, but it does not work.

```
 myTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
 myTextView.highlight(charPos: wordIndexInDocument, length: wordLength)
 myTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

If I comment out the statement with the highlight function, the selected word is not highlighted, but there is no scrolling.  So that line is definitely causing the scrolling.

This code is located in a subclass of a UIView, not UIViewController.

I need the document to stay in place when the user highlights a word.    Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try using `scrollRangeToVisible` and give the range of the highlighted text

```
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
```

Comment: I tried this, and it did keep the document from scrolling to the bottom.   Unfortunately, it causes the screen to blink, which would be very annoying to the end-user.  I think I need a way to actually disable scrolling when using UITextView.highlight.